# How to have a page load lots of text snippets from unique URLs

Tags: javascript

I have a simple web app written in PHP that displays a table of information.  The app needs to request the information from each table cell from a unique URL in order to display the contents and send them to the browser.  Since PHP isn't threaded (and none of the threading add-ons seem to work using my web host) the page takes an extremely long time to load while the server is pulling information sequentially from unique URLs.  I'd like to have the client pull down the unique text snippets for each table cell.

I'm new to Ajax so I'm having trouble figuring out how to make an HTML page that loads unique text snippets upon load.  All of the examples I've been able to find show how to get content to load upon a click or some user action and they appear to be focused around doing it once for one URL in one part of the page.  I need something that works immediately at page load and can be configured to pull down multiple unique URLs.

Can someone point me to a simple resource to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You'll be wanting to call the function that begins loading page content with the onload property of

2.) Use a JavaScript library that supports callbacks when AJAX requests finish loading.

3.) Write a function that iterates through the cells in the table, using setTimeout to call itself on a new index.  Using setTimeout every time the function finishes making an AJAX request on a given item will prevent the page from stopping your script due to execution time.

4.)Construct your AJAX queries and callbacks such that when a query returns, the relevant row is updated.